# Topology - Show that the set $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R : xy = 1\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R : xy = 1\}$ is a closed subset of
$\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=xy$ and $$A=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}.$$

**Proof 1**
$$A=f^{-1}(\{1\}).$$
Since $f$ is continuous, $A$ is closed ($f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for all closed set $F\subset \mathbb R$).

**Proof 2**

Let $(x_n,y_n)\in A^{\mathbb N}$ a convergent sequence. Dnote $(x,y)$ the limit. Then,
$$xy=\lim_{n\to \infty }x_ny_n=1,$$
and thus $(x,y)\in A$. Therefore, $A$ is sequentielly closed, and thus closed.

**Proof 3**

Using the definition, we show that $A^c$ is open. Let $(x,y)\in A^c$. Let $$h=\text{dist}((x,y),A)=\inf\{\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|_2\mid (a,b)\in A\},$$where $\|\cdot \|_2$ is the euclidian norm. This can be easily computed, and this is non zero. Take any $0<\delta <h$. Then $$B((x,y),\delta )=\{(s,t)\in \mathbb R^2\mid \|(x,y)-(s,t)\|_2<\delta\} \subset A^c.$$

Therefore $A^c$ is open, and thus $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that in $\mathbb R^n$ a subset $A$ is closed if and only if all convergent sequences of elements of $A$ has its limit in $A$. Suppose $(x_x,y_n)$ converges to $(x,y)$ and that all $(x_x,y_n)$ are in the set. Then by continuity of the product, $x_n y_n = 1$ converges both to $xy$ and to $1$, so $xy = 1$ and $(x,y)$ is in the set. Therefore the set is closed.

Another proof : the function $f : (x,y) \mapsto xy$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$, so it follows that $f^{<{-1}>}(\{1\})$ is a closed set as the inverse image of a singleton. This set is precisely the one in the question.